# Identity 2 code first database in SQL Express. Where is the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, connection-string, asp.net-identity, sql-server-express

I want to create an MVC 5 project with Individual User Accounts authentication using Identity 2, and i want it to create a SQL Express database, instead of a localDb, using entity framework code first.

My connection string is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MatWeb-20150821085043.mdf;User Instance=True;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MatWeb-20150821085043;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When i run the web app, it launches properly and it let me register a new user, but if i try to check the database with SQL Server Management Studio, it doesn't appear anywhere.

So,
1.- Where is my database?
2.- Is it possible to make it visible with the SQL Server Management Studio? Or maybe change the database file path to make it searchable bu SQL Management Studio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you attached your DB in connection string your DB is in `App_Data` folder of your project.

To manage your DB in Management Studio simply right click in Databases item in Object Explorer panel and choose Attach and add your DB file from `App_Data`